# How to run linux in efi mode after installing in legacy mode?

Tags: uefi

I installed Ubuntu in windows by making separate partition. 
My both OS are installed in legacy mode but I want to switch to UEFI. When I switch to UEFI MODE a black screen comes up instead of grub and it asks me to press ESC. 
Is it possible to switch to UEFI ?
Do I need to make any partition for EFI ?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Switching Linux to boot in EFI mode is relatively easy; you just need to install [the EFI-mode boot loader of your choice,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) although this will require that you create an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and some EFIs also require you to [convert the disk from MBR to GPT.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html)

Switching Windows to boot in EFI mode is harder. The same steps are required, but Windows makes it a bit harder to perform those steps. If you're interested, I recommend you read [this page,](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) which describes the process in detail.

Overall, I'd say it's not worth the hassle unless you've got some compelling reason, such as if you're replacing a sub-2TiB disk with one that's larger than 2TiB (and that therefore requires GPT, and hence an EFI-mode boot of Windows).

Answer (score -1):

The only way is to actually install Ubuntu in the UEFI boot mode.  However, you can keep what ever windows install there.  In windows, run fdisk, there create a second partition, split the drive in half(considering you have the space to pull off.).  At which point, you will then use the USB install point of Ubuntu.

However, since you now have a legacy install and a UEFI install, you will have to pick which boot you want every time.  So you would have to press F12 if you wanted to boot in Windows, which will require a reboot.  Also, please note that GRUB2 might not see Windows because the boot partition will not see legacy.

This [Q&A should answer anything else you want done.](https://superuser.com/questions/676249/clean-install-of-windows-7-pro-64-bit-on-a-uefi-with-gpt-laptop)

Comment: Actually, a conversion without re-installing the whole OS is possible. I've done it several times, especially with Linux.

Comment: You provided an answer than tell them its harder than what mine requires?  Then down vote it?